# rosrun can give output (images) in a folder while roslaunch cannot

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using ros to generate some imaes to do control. The node I use can generate a folder named "ImageFolder" under catkin_ws folder. And some images will be saved to ImageFolder after the code. However, when I use launch file to launch the same node, the terminal will give me `cannot mkdir ImageFolder, it exists`, even I delete the ImageFolder before launch this file. Of course, the new images is not printed in this folder either. The launch file I use is the simplest one, with only type, pkg, name arguments. Does anyone know what's the reason? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358689/rosrun-can-give-output-(images)-in-a-folder-while-roslaunch-cannot/) by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use roslaunch and then make or save files/directories, those files and directories are created at `$ROS_HOME`, typically set to `/home/user/.ros/`. I suggest you look at that location for your images.

Additionally, you can specify a location to write files to using a parameter for your node. In your launch file you can set that parameter, and even have it be relative to a package. See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML, specifically the `$(find pkg)` syntax.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2020-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jason](https://answers.ros.org/users/29292/jason/) on 2020-08-05**:
Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. It is in the invisible ".ros".
Then I tried to specificy a path from "imageFolder" to "~/catkin_ws/imageFolder" in the code. However, both roslaunch and  rosrun can generate this folder but cannot write images to it.
Then I switch back to make it generated in the executable file directory using
`<launch> <node name="test" pkg="my_package" type="my_node" cwd="node" /> </launch>`